# Jquery remove element and remove the associated li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i click a link and copy a div and create a li for this copied div into the ul list. When i remove a created div, the counter resets the elements, but how can i update or remove the associated li that i created? I tested many things. Firstly i checked the text of the div that clicked to remove and if text is same as a li text then remove the li. That is working, but i removed it, sometimes there was a bit weired behavier, perhaps you can help me here too. But how can i update the li. For example added three new entries: Test2, Test3, Test4. Now i removed Test3, it recounts the Div Texts to Test2,Test3, but in the li list it is: Test2,Test4. So, would be great if you help me: to delete the associated li when element removed and recount the associated li -> text and id when resetindexes. I searched many times, but have no clue :-(

```js
            function resetIndexes(){
                var j = 1;   
                $('.p_scnt').each(function(){
                    if( j > 1){
                        $(this).attr('name', 'p_scnt_' + j);
                        $(this).text('Test '+j);
                    }
                    j++;
                });
            }

            $(function() {
                var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
                var i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;

                $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                    i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;   
                    $('#section-one-a1').clone().appendTo('#p_scents').prop('id', 'section-one-a' + i);
                    $('<li id="sec-a'+i+'"><a href="#section-one-a'+i+'">Test '+i+'</a></li>').insertBefore("#addnew_a");
                    $("#section-one-a"+i+ " #p_scnt").text('Test '+" " +i);
                    $('#section-one-a'+i+ ' #remove').css("visibility", "visible");
                    $('#section-one-a'+i+ ' .remScnt').css("pointer-events", "auto");
                    i++;
                    return false;
                });
                

                $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() { 
                    if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('span').remove();
                        resetIndexes();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test">
            <li class="static">Static</li>
            <li id="sec-a1">Test 1</li>
            <li id="addnew_a"><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add new Set</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <div id="p_scents">
            <span id="section-one-a1">
                <div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>
                    <span id="remove" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#" style="color: black; pointer-events: none;" class="remScnt">Remove</a></span>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign custom attribute to your `li` tag which is added dynamically and add that as well to your span tags then whenever your `remove` is click get the `data-attribute` of span and use this to remove `li` then reassign values to all elements .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function resetIndexes() {
  var j = 1;
  $('.p_scnt:not(:first)').each(function() {
    j++;
    $(this).attr('name', 'p_scnt_' + j);
    $(this).text('Test ' + j);
    $(this).parent().attr("data-span", j) //add new data attr
    $(this).parent().attr('id', "section-one-a" + j)
  });

}

function reset_list() {
  var j = 1
  //loop through dynamically created lis
  $('li[data-value]').each(function(index) {
    j++;
    $(this).attr('id', 'sec-a' + j); //chnage id
    $(this).attr("data-value", j) //chnage data value
    $(this).find("a").attr('href', '#section-one-a ' + j);
    $(this).find("a").text('Test ' + j)
  });

}
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;
    $('#section-one-a1').clone().appendTo('#p_scents').prop('id', 'section-one-a' + i);
    $('<li id="sec-a' + i + '" data-value=' + i + '><a href="#section-one-a' + i + '">Test ' + i + '</a></li>').insertBefore("#addnew_a");
    $("#section-one-a" + i).attr("data-span", i)
    $("#section-one-a" + i + " #p_scnt").text('Test ' + " " + i);
    $('#section-one-a' + i + ' #remove').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#section-one-a' + i + ' .remScnt').css("pointer-events", "auto");
    i++;
    return false;
  });


  $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      var dat_span = $(this).closest('span[data-span]').data("span") //get attribute of span to remove
      $(this).parents('span').remove();
      $("#test li[data-value=" + dat_span + "]").remove() //use same to remove li
      resetIndexes();
      reset_list();

    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test">
  <li class="static">Static</li>
  <li id="sec-a1">Test 1</li>
  <li id="addnew_a"><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add new Set</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="p_scents">
  <span id="section-one-a1">
                <div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>
                    <span id="remove" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#" style="color: black; pointer-events: none;" class="remScnt">Remove</a></span>
  </span>
</div>
```